# Same Hasura query executed with hugely different execution times

Tags: performance, graphql, delay, hasura

While sending periodically the same graph query to Hasura server, I have observed significantly different execution times

In one of the these cases, the query was executed under a single seconds, where as in another case the same query took more than 150 seconds. The execution times were captures from the Hasura "http-log" statements.

An additional observation from the corresponding "query-log" statements is that, the SQLs are generated in both cases, within similar times.

Any reason for the generated SQL being executed after a significant and considerable delay compared to the other.

Any specific reason for this inconsistent behaviour and any specific configurations that can be made to overcome this issue.

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the applicable script and/or code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that counts as an answer, it's certainly not "a general case answer" as it reflects only our experience.

We encountered similar problem: inconsistent latencies for the same queries.

Where we looked and what we found.

## 1. hasura

Hasura itself is a very thin and predictable layer above postgresql (and now other DBs too).

I'm not a haskel expert but I got impression that SQL generation comes from here: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/blob/b2461c5899a881183ad2d269ebe8a2c6f55e46af/server/src-lib/Hasura/GraphQL/Execute/LiveQuery.hs

(I could be wrong and I will be grateful if somebody will correct me)

So:

- hasura always generate the same SQL for the same query
- this process is predictable
- it has a low cost

Conclusion: hasura itself could not be source of different latencies. We need to look on DB level

## 2. What we encountered on DB level

We build a simple test: running the same query on DB

And we discovered that the same query is running as 100ms-100ms-2 seconds - 150 ms - 3 seconds - 90 ms.

We search for locks - and did not found them.

We looked on buffering - and discovered that almost all DB is cached in memory.

Finally our suspicion was that it's Azure Database (we used cloud postgresql from MS) is misbehaving.

We contacted support (and we had other questions to them) and finally we discovered that we simply hit IOPS limit.

This hypothesis was supported by simple fact: if we run `VACUUM/REINDEX/ REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW/heavy procedures` then DB became much less responsive for an amount of time.

We considered upgrading Azure Database but we had other problems and we wanted to upgrade postgresql version so finally we decided to migrate to Amazon RDS.

(That's not bashing Azure or promoting Amazon, personally I think that running on-premise would be the best)

After that all strange execution times disappeared.

Think yourself how that reflects your case.

In general I recommend to look on DB level only.